# Mutating a column that isn't the same length

Tags: r, dplyr

With an existing column, I want to sequence a list of dates to each row e.g.

```
tibble(x = c("a", "b", "c"))

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  x    
  <chr>
1 a    
2 b    
3 c
```

How do I tweak mutate to give me this output?

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  x     dates     
  <chr> <date>    
1 a     2021-01-01
2 a     2021-01-02
3 a     2021-01-03
4 b     2021-01-01
5 b     2021-01-02
6 b     2021-01-03
7 c     2021-01-01
8 c     2021-01-02
9 c     2021-01-03
```

Comment: Take a look at `?tidyr::expand_grid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr::crossing`

```
df <- tibble(x = c("a", "b", "c"))

dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-03'), by = '1 day')
tidyr::crossing(df, dates)

#   x     dates     
#  <chr> <date>    
#1 a     2021-01-01
#2 a     2021-01-02
#3 a     2021-01-03
#4 b     2021-01-01
#5 b     2021-01-02
#6 b     2021-01-03
#7 c     2021-01-01
#8 c     2021-01-02
#9 c     2021-01-03
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% uncount(weights = 3) %>% group_by(x) %>% 
   mutate(dates = as.Date('2021-01-01') + row_number()-1)
# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   x [3]
  x     dates     
  <chr> <date>    
1 a     2021-01-01
2 a     2021-01-02
3 a     2021-01-03
4 b     2021-01-01
5 b     2021-01-02
6 b     2021-01-03
7 c     2021-01-01
8 c     2021-01-02
9 c     2021-01-03
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  x    
  <chr>
1 a    
2 b    
3 c
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `expand_grid`

```
library(tidyr)
expand_grid(df, dates)
```